# What does unaligned mean in an APK file in Qt/Android?

Tags: android, qt, build, apk, difference

When I build my Android package using Qt Creator, I receive two apk files. One named `Qt-Debug.apk`and another one named `Qt-Debug-unaligned.apk`. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unaligned" means that it is not zip-aligned ...

zip-aligned is the process to optimize the apk size thats all...

zipalign is an archive alignment tool that provides important optimization to Android application (.apk) files. The purpose is to ensure that all uncompressed data starts with a particular alignment relative to the start of the file

Comment: Thanks for answer, as I see better to deploy aligned apk to device?